# Sublime Text 2 - Problems with HTML automatic element on return

Tags: sublimetext2

Hi everytime I hit return after an html element sublime propose a wierd auto completion element : like this div> after I hit return after a closing div element

Very very annoying

Thx

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19746745/edit) your post to describe exactly the type of problem you are having, with example code or screenshots, what you think you should be seeing, and any steps you've taken to troubleshoot or fix it. Please also list any relevant plugins you have installed, like code intelligence, HTML snippets, Emmet, etc. As it stands now, there is no question here.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I press a couple of enters after, for example, "</div>", Sublime suggests "div>" as auto complete. Very annoying as the suggestion gets selected on enter key. Don't really want to press esc before every enter. This haven't been a problem until today, though. (Yes, I have restarted the editor, even the computer).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, removing the SublimeCodeIntel package resolved my issue.